# Set variable on multiple case within each group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case, exists

Say I have below table

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cis | aid | cid | apid | ntime | buid | flg | jid |
| 30 | 1208 | 229067737 | 1026 | 9 | DDDD400C | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | 1209 | 229067737 | 1026 | 11 | DDDD400C | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | 0 | 229067737 | 1026 | 12 | DDDD400C | 1 | 100 |
| 30 | 1210 | 229067737 | 1026 | 13 | DDDD400C | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | 0 | 229067737 | 1026 | 14 | DDDD400C | 1 | 101 |

```
CREATE TABLE Aiarcle
(cis INT, aid INT, cid INT, apid INT, ntime INT, buid VARCHAR(MAX), flg INT, jid INT) 
INSERT INTO Aiarcle
(cis, aid, cid, apid, ntime, buid, flg, jid) 
VALUES (30, 1208, 229067737, 1026, 9, 'DDDD400C', 0, 0)
      ,(30, 1209, 229067737, 1026, 11, 'DDDD400C', 0, 0)
      ,(30,    0, 229067737, 1026, 12, 'DDDD400C', 1, 100)
      ,(30, 1210, 229067737, 1026, 13, 'DDDD400C', 0, 0)
      ,(30,    0, 229067737, 1026, 14, 'DDDD400C', 1, 101);
```

Now I need to do following here. First filter out rows `WHERE ntime > 10`.

```
SELECT * FROM Aiarcle WHERE ntime > 10
```

Then all I need to do is check in a single statement if `flg 0` and `flg 1` esists in my table and set both variables.

This is what I did, but this does not works.

```
DECLARE @flg0Exists BIT = 1
DECLARE @flg1Exists BIT  = 1


SELECT @flg0Exists = CASE WHEN flg = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       @flg1Exists = CASE WHEN flg = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       FROM Aiarcle WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE nTime > 10
       
SELECT @flg0Exists, @flg1Exists
```

The output of which was

[image]

**Note** that I don't want to split the statements, need to do above in a single statement.

Comment: Show desired final output.

Comment: `1 and 1` if present

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` to check if flag 0 and 1 exists.

IF MIN(flg) = 0 this means that flag 0 exists

IF MAX(flg) = 1 this means that flag 1 exists.

```
DECLARE @flg0Exists BIT = 1;
DECLARE @flg1Exists BIT  = 1;

SELECT @flg0Exists = CASE WHEN src.min_flg = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       @flg1Exists = CASE WHEN src.max_flg = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
(
SELECT MIN(Flg) as min_flg,
      MAX(flg) as max_flg
FROM Aiarcle
WHERE nTime > 10
)as src;

SELECT @flg0Exists as flg0Exists, @flg1Exists as flg1Exists;
```

| flg0Exists | flg1Exists |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gkOyGpGF)

IF `flg` can have other values besides 0 and 1 , you can filter out the records to 0 and 1 , like this:

```
SELECT MIN(Flg) as min_flg,
      MAX(flg) as max_flg
FROM Aiarcle
WHERE nTime > 10
  and flg >=0
  and flg <=1
```